# FileInputStream causing FileNotFoundException - The Process cannot access the file

Tags: java, concurrency, filenotfoundexception, fileinputstream

I am using the Watcher Service to let me watch for the addition or removal of files from a particular directory.  So far I have it working for adding the file and deleting the file.  What I am seeing however is a stacktrace `(java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\data\index.php (The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process)` when I add a file, remove that file, then retry adding that file again.

Here's my the code in question with the error happening within the `try` block of my getDigest Method:

```
public class WatchDir implements Runnable{

        for (WatchEvent<?> event: key.pollEvents()) {
            WatchEvent.Kind kind = event.kind();

            // Context for directory entry event is the file name of entry
            WatchEvent<Path> ev = cast(event);
            Path name = ev.context();
            Path child = dir.resolve(name);

            if(!Files.isDirectory(child, NOFOLLOW_LINKS)){
                //Callable<LftFile> worker;

                try {
                    **this.file = new LftFile(child.toFile(), kind != ENTRY_CREATE);**

                    if(this.file.isDeleted()){
                        // Update DB, set deleted flag              

                    } else {    
                        // Add to DB
                        }                       

                } catch (Exception e1) {
                    logger.error("...");
                }                   
            }

...
...

   }
}




    // this is a method within the LftFile.  It reads in the file's content
    // and creates a crc on it.  This is for future validation.
private static long getDigest(File f) {
    long crc = -1;
    try ( **InputStream in = new FileInputStream(f)** ) {   // <--- ERRS HERE
        CRC32 crcMaker = new CRC32();
        byte[] buffer = new byte[2048];
        int bytesRead;
        while((bytesRead = in.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            crcMaker.update(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
        }
        crc = crcMaker.getValue();  
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }   
    return crc;
}
```

Comment: try with private static **synchronized** long getDigest(File f) {

Comment: I tried that, unfort. it doesn't seem to be a threading issue.  It seems to be a file handle issue.  Windows seems to be holding onto the file...

Comment: Try to operate with `*.txt` instead.

Comment: I dont understand.  What do you mean try to operate with *.txt?  You mean only use .txt files?

Comment: Windows does not protect txt files. Maybe it works

Comment: That's not a valid solution.  This has to work for all file types.

Comment: Do you have other code which may touch the same file at the same time?

Comment: I dont believe so.  I think it is the way Windows handles 'file handles'.

Comment: Some code you don't show here -- in particular when you delete the file. Do you use `Files.delete()`?

Comment: No, I never call delete on the file (in Java - I do go to the file system manually and hit the 'Delete' key ).  Programmatically, I just update the database's "isDeleted" flag.

If another process is using the file, how would I find out which one it was to kill it?

Comment: Could it be child.toFile() (which returns a File)?  If so, how would I close that first???

Comment: Are you closing all your streams (for example the InputSteam in getDigest)? To find out which process is locking a file use something like [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx)

Comment: I have all wrapped in a try-with-rec.  I'll give Process Explorer a try

Comment: I tried it and it doesn't help very much.  It still isnt clear what is holding onto that file

Comment: I have same problem in the watcher service.